# Limit Q-Select choices line number

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

using a q-select in order to choose options. But if there is to many the q-select content grows in so much lines. I want to limit to 2 lines :
[image: Too many opts example]

```
              <q-select
            v-model="option.selectedDocuments"
            :options="option.tasks"
            :readonly="selectedOption !== option"
            option-label="title"
            multiple
            emit-value
            use-chips
            stack-label
            @input="handleTaskEditionAdd"
          >
            <template v-slot:option="scope">
              <q-item
                :data-test-id="`el-select-option-${scope.index}`"
                v-bind="scope.itemProps"
                v-on="scope.itemEvents"
              >
                <q-item-section
                  :class="{'text-feedback-success-darkest': selectedOption.selectedDocuments.includes(scope.opt)}"
                >
                  <q-item-label v-html="scope.opt.title" />
                </q-item-section>
                <q-item-section
                  v-if="selectedOption.selectedDocuments.includes(scope.opt)"
                  side
                >
                  <q-icon name="mdi-check" color="primary"/>
                </q-item-section>
              </q-item>
            </template>
          </q-select>
```

Comment: add CSS styling `max-height`

Comment: @yoduh where ? I tried but this didn't worked

Comment: You'd need to inspect the DOM to figure it out.  Looks like you want `.q-select .q-field__native`. [codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/YzBWbem)